# ¿Como puedo transmitir un UDP multicast a internet en formato m3u8 en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stream, tcpudp

por el momento recibo una señal de prueba por protocolo udp (con IP multicast) y quisiera transmitirla por internet, según veía en una [pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052883/create-m3u8-file-from-list-of-ts-files) se deben crear archivos .ts segmentados que almacenen los bytes recibidos (por lo que entiendo algo como en caché) y a partir de ellos generar una lista m3u8 para su transmisión, mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo se generan esos archivos .ts? ¿Debo obtener un segmento de bytes y almacenarlo en cada .ts e irlos creando y borrando?